# Numerical optimisation over quantum states/measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, optimization

Suppose we need to find a quantum state and set of measurement basis that optimise a given function of these parameters. This is quite common for e.g. in finding optimal violation of some bell inequality. What are the standard ways of doing this numerically (it needs to be as efficient as possible because we are dealing with large number of independent variables here) ? Essentially, whats the best way to parameterise these states and measurements, and which numerical packages are efficient for such computation ? Thanks !

Comment: I don't think there are standard ways to do this. The most suitable tools and techniques will depend strongly on the kind of optimisation you are dealing with (that is, what function is being optimised)